# A problem on derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let the function $g$ have a continuous second derivative, and let $g(x^*)=0$, $g'(x^*)\neq 0$. Then for points $\eta$ in a region near $x^*$ there is a $k_1$ such that $|g''(\eta)| < k_1$ and a $k_2$ such that $|g'(\eta)| > k_2$. I could not understand why this should be true ?

Comment: Hint: $|g'|$ is a continuous and non-zero at $x^{\ast}$. $|g''|$ is continuous and hence bounded on compact sets.

Answer (score 1):

Any continuous function is bounded on compact sets, hence on $[x^*-1,x^*+1]$, the function $g''$ is bounded. Let $k_1 = 1+\sup_{x \in [x^*-1,x^*+1]} g''(x)$.

Since $g'$ is continuous, and $g'(x^*) \neq 0$, there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $k_2 = \min_{x \in [x^*-\epsilon,x^*+\epsilon]} |g'(x)| >0$.